# Using docker for only some processes in Nextflow

Tags: docker, nextflow

I am writing a pipeline in Nextflow, which contains multiple processes, where most of them use docker. Now I am trying to add a new process which includes only a python script to preprocess some results - no docker image needed.

However, I get the error `Missing container image for process 'my_python_process'`.

I define the docker images in nextflow.config as follows:

```
process {
    withName:process1 {
        container = 'some/image1:1.0'
    }
    withName:process2{
        container = 'some/image2:1.0'
    }
    withName:process3{
        container = 'some/image3:1.0'
    }
}

docker {
    enabled = true
}
```

I found a discussion, where they suggested using `container = null` for the process without container, but it still gives the same error, no matter what the process script contains.

Does anyone know what I'm missing please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `docker.enabled = true`, Nextflow will try to run each process in a Docker container created using the specified image. You then get the error you're seeing when the [container](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#container) directive has not been specified for a particular process. The usual way is to just specify a 'base' or 'default' container for your workflow. You may want to choose one that comes with Python. Otherwise, Ubuntu would be a good choice in my opinion.

Note that the `withName` [process selector](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#process-selectors) has the highest priority<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#selector-priority)</sup>.

```
process {

    container = 'ubuntu:22.04'

    withName: my_python_process {
        container = 'python:3.9'
    }

    withName: process1 {
        container = 'some/image1:1.0'
    }
    withName: process2 {
        container = 'some/image2:1.0'
    }
    withName: process3 {
        container = 'some/image3:1.0'
    }
}

docker {
    enabled = true
}
```

I'm not aware of a way to disable Docker execution for a particular process, but nor would you really want to<sup>[2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/container.html#containers)</sup>. The above approach should be preferred:

> Containerization allows you to write self-contained and truly
> reproducible computational pipelines, by packaging the binary
> dependencies of a script into a standard and portable format that can
> be executed on any platform that supports a container runtime.
> Furthermore, the same pipeline can be transparently executed with any
> of the supported container runtimes, depending on which runtimes are
> available in the target compute environment.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. I was not sure if using container for all the processes was the right way to go and could not find any relevant documentation. Now I know, thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that (a) it is not possible to have only some of the processes running within Docker containers and that (b) this has been discussed among the developers and there are no plans to have this "feature". Also worth mentioning is that in some executors (cloud computing such as using Google Batch), a container image is required (and will be used) regardless of `docker.enabled = true` or `-with-docker`.